# C++: check if a certain exception type was thrown without external libraries

Tags: c++, exception, testing

I am writing up some tests for a C++ program and I would like to check that my program throws certain types of exceptions when given certain inputs. I have seen that this is doable using external libraries such as googletest, but I would like to know how this was implemented.

I would like to separate the test data from the test code as much as possible. In particular, I would like something like this:

```
void RunTests(InputList inputs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (FunctionIAmTesting(inputs[i].value) has the expected exception behavior) {
            // Pass
        } else {
            // Fail
        }
    }
}

InputList inputs = InputList({
     Input(5),                         // no exception when 5 is an input
     Input<MyExceptionClass>(0),       // MyExceptionClass thrown when 0 is an input
     Input<MyOtherExceptionClass>(-1)  // MyOtherExceptionClass thrown when -1 is an input
});

RunTests(inputs);
```

Comment: Can't be bothered to look at the source code of the myriad of unit testing libraries out there?

Comment: Which dependency do you mean? At compiling or/and linking time?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Technically every answer asked on Stack Overflow is out there somewhere, but it may be nontrivial to dig up. The point of this site is to make that information more accessible so that people don't have to spend as much time reading source code or documentation.

Comment: @dnk My real purpose is to learn how this was implemented. I've edited the question to remove the bit about the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

If you know what the type of exception you are looking for then you can target an exception of that type in the `catch ()` statement.

```
try {
    // Test code.

    // Unexpected success
    std::cerr << "Expected a RelevantException to be thrown." << std::endl;
}
catch (RelevantException& e)
{
    // Expected exception, continue.
}
catch (...) // Catch all
{
    // Unexpected exception
    std::cerr << "Unexpected exception encountered, expected "
                 "RelevantException." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Always catch by reference!

Comment: Whoops! Good `catch`.

Comment: @AndrewDunn I apologize for not being specific enough when I originally asked my question. I updated it to more accurately reflect what I am looking for. Basically, I have a lot of test inputs, and I would like to separate them from the test code, as well as keep everything as less verbose as possible.

Answer (score 0):

A several years back I wrote some simple library for "mocking" objects. And my goal was to check everything related to function calls. In the tests I wrote something like that:

```
MyMockedObject my;
mock::expect(my, "foo").in(10).out(20).returns(30);
mock::expect(my, "bar").throws(logic_error("bar failed"));

int v;
// test that my::baz() invokes my.foo(10, v)
// then my.bar which fails with the exception
my.baz();
```

Your task seems to be a little bit easier. All that you need is a way how to describe your expectations and some hack in the test runner to verify them at the end of a test (accordingly to the input). Your expectations are exceptions, just construct them somehow and associate with the input. In your example you did a half part of your work.

```
typedef std::map<Input, Exception> Expectations;
typedef std::pair<Input, Exception> Expectation;

// somewhere before the tests
expectations.insert(make_pair(Input(5)), NoThrowAnything);
expectations.insert(make_pair(Input(0)), MyException("some message"));
expectations.insert(make_pair(Input(-1)), MyOtherException("another message"));

void run_test(const Expectation& expect)
{
  try {
    // run the real test here based on Input (expect.first)
    check_expectation(expect);
  } catch (const Exception& ex) {
    check_expectation(expect, ex);
  }
}

void run_all_tests(const Expectations& expects)
{
  for (e : expects) {
    try {
      run_test(e);
    } catch (const ExpectationException ex) {
       // failed expectation
    }
  }
}

void check_expectation(const Expectation& expect)
{
  if (expect.second != NoThrowAnything) {
    throw ExpectationFailure(expect);
  }
}

void check_expectation(const Expectation& expect, const Exception& ex)
{
  if (expect.second != ex) {
    throw ExpectationMismatch(expect, ex);
  }
}
```

Comment: The part that I am not sure how to do is the third line of my example. Do you have any advice regarding how to do that?

Comment: I would catch them in the test runner hook. Then just compare on equality against expectations.

Comment: Could you give me some more details about how to do this? I am not sure how I can obtain the exception class from the Input object, nor what to do when no exception is expected.

Comment: I've just added an example. It just expresses an idea and doesn't pretend to be the complete solution. :-)